# C++ using this pointer in constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, this

Is it legal to use `this` pointer in constructor initialization list in following case? I'm trying to start some background thread with task which is class method. Is it a good approach at all, can I do better? It works with clang (LLVM 3.5), but I'm afraid of undefined behavior.

```
class SomeClass  {
    public:
        SomeClass();

    private:
        std::thread syncThread;
        void syncTask();
};


SomeClass::SomeClass()
    :syncThread(&SomeClass::syncTask, this) { // is it legal? object is under construction
}
```

Comment: Please search before posting.  Thanks.

Comment: @Oliver I've searched, suggest I should improve my search skills..